# Why can't my code generate more than 999 text files?

Tags: c, text, plaintext

The code compiles and runs, however I try change the variable `cant=2000`, but fail to generate 2000 file as I hope.

the code is here.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

//  Usando Preprocesado para manejar las matrices y tener acceso eficiente a memoria
    #define F(i,j) F[i*col +j]  
    #define B(i,j) B[i*col +j]

float randfloat(float min, float max){    
    return ((float) rand() / (float) RAND_MAX);   
}

int i, j, tstep, fil, col, cant;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    char nombre_b[50] ;     //= "";
    char nombre_f[50] ;     //= "";      
    FILE *puntero_f;
    FILE *puntero_b;

    fil = 2;
    col = 2;
    cant = 1000;

    int tam = fil*col;
    float *F = calloc(tam,sizeof(float));
    float *B = calloc(tam,sizeof(float));

    //srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

    int archi = 0;
    for (tstep=0; tstep<cant; tstep++){

        sprintf(nombre_f, "Forward%d.txt", tstep);
        sprintf(nombre_b, "Backward%d.txt", tstep);
        puntero_f = fopen(nombre_f, "a+");
        puntero_b = fopen(nombre_b, "a+");

        for(i = 0; i<fil; i++){
            for(j = 0; j<col; j++){
                F(i,j) = randfloat(0.0f, 1.0f);
                B(i,j)  = randfloat(0.0f, 1.0f);

                if(tstep==archi){
                    fprintf(puntero_f,"%f ", F(i,j));
                    fprintf(puntero_b,"%f ", B(i,j));
                }
            }
            if(tstep==archi){
                fprintf(puntero_f,"\n");
                fprintf(puntero_b,"\n");
            }
        }
        archi++;
        fclose(puntero_f);
        fclose(puntero_b);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: STANDARD ADVICE: Before asking us, try adding a printout or two, or running it under a debugger, and let the program itself tell you what you're doing wrong. Are you sure you're actually running the newly compiled version?

Comment: If `fopen` fails, the system tells you why.  Ask the system.  `puntero_f = fopen(...);  if( puntero_f == NULL ) { perror( nombre_f ) ; ...`

Comment: As others said, you can query the return value of `fopen`. I know that some disk filing systems only allow a fixed number of entries in their top level directory, and that could fail. Or it could be your storage medium is full. Of file names like `Forward1000.txt` may be too long for your disk filing system, etc. There can be many reasons.

Comment: Assuming a unix-like system, what are your ulimits?

Answer (score 1):

Question: Why can't my code generate more than 999 text files?

Answer: The question code, after execution, generates 2000 files (which is more than 999).

Forward0 through Forward999, and Backward0 through Backward999.

The limiting factors:

```
cant = 1000;
```

and

```
for (tstep=0; tstep<cant; tstep++)
```

Go generate more than 0-999 (x2) files, change the value of cant to the number of files you wish to generate.

---

Perhaps you wish to generate files postfixed from 1 to 2000?  If so, change:

```
cant = 2000;
```

and

```
for (tstep=1; tstep<=cant; tstep++)
```

Answer (score 0):

excuse...

I don't know the reason, but today i turn on my pc, run the same code and works fine is very strange.

i believe the same than Rudy, but muy parent directory is located in the home folder, isn't posible that name file generated exceed limits of S.O, but i'll have your suggestion for future work.